# Counting/Pivot of Table With Multiple Values In Cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got some data that looks like this:

```
Class                    Instructor
Intro to Philosophy      Jake
Algorithms               Ashley/Jake
Spanish I                Ashley
Vector Calculus          Jake
Intro to Philosophy      Jake
```

How can I get to a count or pivot that looks like below where the instance that Ashley and Jake both teach a class is properly added to the counts? The instance of one instructor is trivial, but two or more for a single class in the same cell is tripping me up.

I'd like to get to something like this:

```
                         Jake        Ashley
Intro to Philosophy         2             0
Algorithms                  1             1
Spanish I                   0             1
Vector Calculus             1             0
Total                       4             2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.str.get_dummies` to split and binarize the `Instructor` field. Then you can groupby `Class`:

```
ret = (df['Instructor'].str.get_dummies('/')
     .groupby(df['Class']).sum()
)
ret.loc['Total'] = ret.sum()
```

Output:

```
                     Ashley  Jake
Class                            
Algorithms                1     1
Intro to Philosophy       0     2
Spanish I                 1     0
Vector Calculus           0     1
Total                     2     4
```

Comment: This is great. Clear and concise. Thank you so much.

Comment: What if I added another level of complexity by adding in a course date with rows based on students like this:
```
Student      Class                  Course Date     Instructor
Alex         Intro to Philosophy    11/4/20     Jake
James        Algorithms             11/5/20         Ashley/Jake
Mike         Spanish I              11/7/20         Ashley
Steven       Vector Calculus        11/5/20         Jake
Denise       Intro to Philosophy    11/8/20         Jake
Carol        Intro to Philosophy    11/8/20         Jake
```
How could I get one count for a teacher per class date?

Comment: `.groupby([df['Class'], df['Date']])`?

Comment: I tried that, and it creates a multiindex with Course/Date, and I'd like to collapse those into one count, so if I had Algorithms/2020-10-22, Algorithms/2020-10-23, and Algorithms/2020-10-24, I just get a count of 3 for that instructor

Comment: Then use `df['Course/Date'].str.extract('^([^/]+)')`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
In [1746]: df.Instructor = df.Instructor.str.split('/')

In [1747]: df = df.explode('Instructor')

In [1751]: x = df.groupby('Instructor').Class.value_counts().reset_index(level=0).pivot(columns='Instructor', values='Class').fillna(0)

In [1754]: x.loc['Total'] = x.sum()

In [1755]: x
Out[1755]: 
Instructor           Ashley  Jake
Class                            
Algorithms              1.0   1.0
Intro_to_Philosophy     0.0   2.0
Spanish_I               1.0   0.0
Vector_Calculus         0.0   1.0
Total                   2.0   4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `crosstab` after `explode`

```
df.Instructor = df.Instructor.str.split('/')

df = df.explode('Instructor')

out = pd.crosstab(df['Class'], df['Instructor'])
```