# Counting/Pivot of Table With Multiple Values In Cell Follow Up

Tags: python, pandas

Follow up to: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806044/counting-pivot-of-table-with-multiple-values-in-cell/64806163)

I've got some data that looks like this:

```
Student      Class                  Course Date     Instructor
Alex         Intro to Philosophy    11/4/20         Jake
James        Algorithms             11/5/20         Ashley/Jake
Mike         Spanish I              11/7/20         Ashley
Steven       Vector Calculus        11/5/20         Jake
Denise       Intro to Philosophy    11/8/20         Jake
Carol        Intro to Philosophy    11/8/20         Jake
```

How can I get to a count or pivot that looks like below where a class on a given date counts once for an instructor.

I'd like to get to something like this:

```
                         Jake        Ashley
Intro to Philosophy         2             0
Algorithms                  1             1
Spanish I                   0             1
Vector Calculus             1             0
Total                       4             2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 'Instructor' is the target columns to pivot columns (I did though it was 'Student' by mistake), one should split and explode the data in order to apply the pivot_table as provided in the original answer.

Modification provided by the own user on comments:

```
df.Instructor = df.Instructor.str.split('/')
df = df.explode('Instructor')
```

Then:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Class', columns='Instructor', values='Student', aggfunc=pd.Series.count).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

where 'Student' may be any other column of your dataframe.

Comment: I added `df.Instructor = df.Instructor.str.split('/')`
and 
`df = df.explode('Instructor')` before this, and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I thought you're interested in the 'Student' column, sorry about that. I've edited the answer. Anyways, check the @BEN_YO approach in your other question. Although `pivot_table` allows you to specify the `agg` function, if you're only interested in the count, his approach is very worth it to you!